# Extract part of filename?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file in the form of:

```
XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description
```

How can I get just the file name `XXX XXXX XXX`?
I've tried:

```
for file in $(ls .d*)
do
    fname="${file%*-}"
    ext="${filename%.*}"
done
```

Comment: Note: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not parse the output of `ls` (see e.g. [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)).  The issue that you're running into is that your loop variable, `file`, will take the values of your filenames after they have all been concatenated into a single long string and then split on whitespaces (and after any split-up word that happens to be a globbing pattern has been expanded).  You'll get three iterations of your loop for the filename `XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description`, for example, one each for the values `XXX`, `XXXX`, and `XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description`.

To iterate over all files that have a dash in their names and then a filename suffix of `.description` use

```bsh
for name in *-*.description; do ...; done
```

To pick out the part before the `-` in `$name`, use a standard parameter expansion that removes everything after the first `-` in the string:

```bsh
prefix=${name%%-*}
```

The difference between using `%%` and `%` here is that with `%%` the *longest* matching tail string is removed.  This matters if there happens to be multiple `-` characters in any name.

Your loop then becomes

```bsh
for name in *-*.description; do
    prefix=${name%%-*}
done
```

The filename suffix is already known (`.description`), but you can can get the bit of the filename from the `-` to the suffix using

```bsh
infix=${name#"$prefix"}
infix=${infix%.description}
```

Finally, with a script like

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

suffix=.description

for name in *-*"$suffix"; do
    prefix=${name%%-*}
    infix=${name#"$prefix"}
    infix=${infix%.description}

    printf 'prefix="%s", infix="%s", suffix="%s"\n' \
        "$prefix" "$infix" "$suffix"
done
```

you'll get

```
$ ls
XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description          XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuK.description
XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuJ.description          script
```

```
$ ./script
prefix="XXX XXXX XXX", infix="-6VwvOkZvzuI", suffix=".description"
prefix="XXX XXXX XXX", infix="-6VwvOkZvzuJ", suffix=".description"
prefix="XXX XXXX XXX", infix="-6VwvOkZvzuK", suffix=".description"
```

Comment: Awesome ! thanks so much/

Comment: @Dark_Stoner Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved. If another answer was more helpful, then accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

I'll leave my answer up, but add the warning from @Kusalananda's answer: Do not
parse the output of `ls` (see e.g.
[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)).

#### My answer

You could pipe the output of ls directly into sed and substitute just the part
coming before the hyphen (`-`):

```
ls *.d* | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'
```

I tried this with two files called:

```
XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI (copy).description
XXX XXXX XYZ-6VwvOkZvzuI.description
```

and the output is:

```
XXX XXXX XXX
XXX XXXX XYZ
```

The way the sed command is working is as follows:

- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)` which in this
  case is everything up to the *last* hyphen in the file name (you'd need to
  adapt it if your files have later hyphens in the names)
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1` - i.e. just the XXX part

You can put the output of the command into a file if needed with:

```
ls *.d* | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' > new_file
```

Comment: Thnx I'll try it now

Comment: if I need everything but the extension would sed be one solution?

Comment: It all depends on how the files are named - if there is only a single dot before the extension (as in your examples in the OP), you could do `ls *.d* | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`, but if you have files like `filename.my.ext` that method would return `filename.my`

Comment: @Dark_Stoner I think the answer by Kusalananda is better than mine so you should probably go with that approach

Comment: This worked for my situation the file structure will never change.fname=$(ls *.d* | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//')

Comment: @Dark_Stoner awesome, I'm glad you could tweak my approach to your situation maybe you could upvote/accept my answer or one of the others (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ ls -1
x.sh
XXX XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description
YYY XXXX XXX-6VwvOkZvzuI.description
$ cat x.sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.d*
do
 fname=${file/-*/}
 ext=${file/*-/}
 echo fname $fname ext $ext
done
$ ./x.sh
fname XXX XXXX XXX ext 6VwvOkZvzuI.description
fname YYY XXXX XXX ext 6VwvOkZvzuI.description
$
```